# redirect to another jsp when struts2 json action method have db connection error

Tags: java, json, jsp, struts2

I have the below thing in struts.xml, Here i am getting Logs as a json , but while getting logs from DB, i need to check a condition, if a db connection is not there redirect to another jsp saying to user "DB Connection is not there".

How to redirect the jsp in struts.xml, when i have the db connection null

```
<action name="getJSONResult" class="com.LogTableAction"  ><!-- method="getLogs"> -->
        <result type="json">
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
            <param name="includeProperties">logs.*</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

**EDIT** *(added from comments)*

```
public class LogTableAction extends ActionSupport { 
    @Override 
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("execute Action: " + ActionContext.getContext().getName()); 
        return SUCCESS; 
    }

    public List<Logs> getLogs() { 
        //Logic to get Logs return Logs; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a doubt about your design.  Does your action return JSON in case of success and redirect to a JSP in case of error?  This doesn't sound fit to me, if you are already making a javascript ajax call it will not matter if you send a redirect with your http response.

I suggest you just return a JSON error code in event of an error and then deal with it properly in the client side (maybe a nice jQuery dialog popping up with an error message?)

Comment: yes , i dont have redirection to jsp for the error, i have only getLogs method, if logs are empty just displaying no records found.
Yes this is an ajax call, Can you please elaborate me/or give any example, how i can set JSON Error code in event of an error? and we are not using JQUERY :( :(

Comment: You are returning something encoded as JSON in your struts 2 action, that object once evaluated in javascript may have some errorCode property that you add if there is some error and then you act accordingly in your client side.  jQuery is just an idea, I just like how it looks xD  The presentation of your error of course is your decision

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this check should'nt be in the struts.xml at all

Secondly I am *assuming* that you establish the connection in the `com.LogTableAction.getLogs()` method. So simply add a check there if the DB connection failes for whatever reason, return an error literal

```
//The method
public String getLogs(){
//..  Some pre-processing

//Try to establish the connection with DB
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(....);
if(c == null) //check if connection was null  
    return "dbError";
}else {
//Continue with the other code
}
```

You can also wrap this check in the try-catch block so that in case of any exception related to DB, `return "dbError"`

Now on your struts.xml, add the entry for handling this new String `dbError`

```
<action name="getJSONResult" class="com.LogTableAction"  ><!-- method="getLogs"> -->
    <result type="json">
        <param name="noCache">true</param>
        <param name="includeProperties">logs.*</param>
    </result>
    <result name="dbError">/pages/your/error/page.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: HI 
the method return value is not String :(

Here is the method signature 

public List<Logs> getLogs(){}

Comment: Then what is your action method that returns String ?

Comment: i have a method getLogs and it returns Logs

Comment: can you post your action class here ?

Comment: public class LogTableAction extends ActionSupport {
    /**
     * 
     */
 
 
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("execute Action: " + ActionContext.getContext().getName());
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Logs> getLogs() {

      //Logic to get Logs
        return Logs;
    }



}

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you call your `getLog()` method via your `execute()` method in the action class. So just add a check in your `getLogs()` method that in case of any DB error, return `null` back to the `execute()` method. Then make a check in your `execute()` method that if `null` is recieved from `getLogs()`, return `dbError`. It will work as I explained